# SCCM uninstall Project Pro, application still detected after uninstallation

Tags: office365, sccm

I've created a deployment in SCCM to uninstall Project Pro if users request this. Other O365 apps need to stay installed. I do this with appdeploy.
The install command is similar to the uninstall command, only containing a different XML file.

```
Execute-Process -Path "$dirFiles\setup.exe" -Parameters "/CONFIGURE uninstallProjectPro.xml"
```

Installing works fine, however uninstalling not. SCCM error is: Application was still detected after uninstallation completed. The logfile contain some errors:
`MsoGetRemoteHostNetworkStatusWithUrlType failed {"RemoteHost": "https://nexus.officeapps.live.com"}`  
As the setup is included in the package, I don't see why it would need to connect to internet to uninstall Project.

When I ran the setup with the xml manually, the uninstall went fine. What am I doing wrong, please?

This is the content of the XML file:

```
<Configuration> 
 <Remove>
    <Product ID="ProjectProRetail" > 
      <Language ID="en-us" /> 
      <Language ID="fr-fr" />
      <Language ID="nl-nl" />
      <Language ID="de-de" />       
    </Product> 
 </Remove>
<Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="TRUE" />
<Logging Level="Standard" Path="c:\logs\Uninstall_Project_Pro2016"/>
<Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE"/>
</Configuration>
```